# Providing an input file location to a Cloud Run Job that's running a Docker Container

Tags: docker, cloud, google-cloud-run

I have got a Docker image pulled and tagged into Artifact Registry. The docker project reads an input file and writes in to an output file.
I'm able to run this command on GCP Shell

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/data us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/skilled-axis-357902/origins2/originsinfo/batch:tag1 --input-file 
/data/inputfile2.csv --output-filepath /data/outputfile.csv --auth-token=tokenvalue  --input-skipheader=1
```

and outputfile.csv gets generated

[image]

I'm trying to run this command in Cloud Run Job and not able to provide the input file as an argument.

Here's how I set up my arguments

[image]

`--auth-token` gets recognized but later I get the following error.

flag provided but not defined: `-volume ${PWD}:/data`

How can I make my input file available for the Cloud Run Job?
I tried using `-v=$PWD:/data , -v $PWD:/data , --volume ${PWD}:/data` but with no luck. I tried providing the file location as  GCS bucket file as well but it didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Here's how I set up my arguments

[image]